# Export role information from a keycloak instance

Tags: keycloak

Is it possible to export the roles added to a keycloak server instance?

I have created some composite roles on a development server which I'd like to mirror across some other instances (e.g. in an integration\development) environment.

The only thing I can think of is using the Admin API to retrieve the details of the roles and use for some sort of insert script to be run in a different environment.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Keycloak 3.2.0.Final and later has a "Export" menu item in its admin console. There you can export groups and roles (global and client roles) to a JSON file.